# Virtualenvwrapper errors on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have just update my Mac from Snow Leopard to Lion. I then needed to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`. I used for both `easy_install`.
I also added virtualenvwrapper settings to my .bash_profile file as following:

```
# virtualenvwrapper settings
export WORKON_HOME="~/virtualenvs"
source "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

But when sourcing it I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not create temporary file name. Make sure TMPDIR is set.
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 
If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, 
check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` is the path to a separately-installed Python 2.7 (possibly from a python.org installer) rather than the Apple-supplied Python 2.7 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`), you need to make sure you are using an `easy_install` for that separate Python or change to using the Apple-supplied Python.  To do either one, you should ensure that your shell PATH variable is correct.  For the first case, you should be able to install an `easy_install` by doing the following:

```
cd /tmp
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON distribute_setup.py
```

You can fix up your shell PATH to include the framework bin directory.  If you are using `bash`, one way would be to add this line to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

Then open a new Terminal session.  You should now find that `easy_install` you just installed is the right one:

```
$ which easy_install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install
```

Comment: Hi Ned "The Python Man" Deily! Thanks really a lot for your answer.
After your answer I thought about that probably I had also to update my Python installation before looking for help. So, that done, on my iMac everyithing worked as expected, while on my Macbook not… :(
I, then, followed your words of wisdom and fixed it. Really, really thank you.
Fyi, both easy_install then pip were in `/usr/local/bin/`. After your directions they are in my `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` (that, btw, I already have it added to my `$PATH` in my `.bash_profile` file).
So, what exaclty `distribute_setup.py` did? tnx

Comment: The easiest way to think about is that each instance of Python has to have its own `easy_install` commnad.  The `distribute_setup.py` script installs a version of `easy_install` for the Python instance that it is running under.

Comment: Thanks again. Hopefully with `virtualenv` in place I should now be able to update to major Python version directly in a virtual environments and to manage specific libraries with other ones.

Being just learning Python, I am sure we'll *meet* again, thanks in advance for your invaluable help.

Comment: I had the problem the other way round: I have my Python installed using homebrew (which creates a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`), but the `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/...:${PATH}"` in `~/.bash_profile` broke things. Commenting out that line fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by exporting $TMPDIR to a saner path, rather than the random crap that Mac OS X prefers.

```
$ grep TMPDIR ~/.env
export TMPDIR=/tmp/

$ source .env
```

and now `virtualenvwrapper` can create its temporary files fine. To make the long story short, just add `export TMP=/tmp/whatever` to your shell runtime configuration file (for example, for ZSH it is `~/.zsh`, for bash it is `~/.bashrc`).